# Getting Videos from server directory to display in container on page using PHP

Tags: php, html, video

I have been trying to modify some PHP to allow my page to get to a directory and its sub-directories to get video files to display dynamically on my page, I'm using the scripts as follows

```
    $imagetypes = array("video/ogv", "video/webm", "video/mp4");
    $dir = "../uploadedVideo/*/";

  function getImages($dir)
  {
    global $imagetypes;

    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();

    // add trailing slash if missing
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

    // full server path to directory
    $fulldir = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/$dir";

    $d = @dir($fulldir) or die("getVideo: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
      // skip hidden files
      if($entry[0] == ".") continue;

      // check for image files
      $f = escapeshellarg("$fulldir$entry");
      $mimetype = trim(`file -bi $f`);
      foreach($imagetypes as $valid_type) {
        if(preg_match("@^{$valid_type}@", $mimetype)) {
          $retval[] = array(
           'file' => "/$dir$entry",
           'size' => getimagesize("$fulldir$entry")
          );
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    $d->close();

    return $retval;
  }
```

This the top of my page before the HTML

This the div I'm looking to display static images or thumbnail, which when clicked on will be viewed in the page

```
  <div class="vidSelect">

<?php
  // fetch image details
  $video = getImages("video");

  // display on page
  foreach($video as $vid) {

      echo "<div class=\"vidContainer\" src=\"{$vid['file']}\"
{$vid['size'][3]}></div>\n";      
 } ?>


  </div>
```

I haven't as yet sorted the video player, as I'm just looking to get the videos to show up first but have run out of ideas and skills to get any further.

It looks as if something is being seen as 3 div containers are being created although there are five sub directories within one main directory I want to access, Any help would be most gratefully received

Comment: Can you add some sample of the results? Nothing is jumping out as wrong.

Comment: Im just getting blank containers, heres the page.  http://www.dot-mov.com/view.php

Comment: First thing I noticed was a trailing or orphaned close tag: `?>` on Line 62 of your HTML Source.

Comment: Second, this line in your loop does not look correct: `echo "<div class=\"vidContainer\" src=\"{$vid['file']}\"
{$vid['size'][3]}></div>\n";` What is the expected result of the Size?

Comment: Third, I think the `type` and `src` attributes are set badly: `<div id="48" name="Test Vid 1" class="vidContainer"><video width="80" height="60"><source src="video/http://www.dot-mov.com/uploadedVideo/testing1/1 hour of  motorcycle crashes.ogv" type="video/.ogg" />Your browser does not support the HTML5 tags.</video></div>`

Answer (score 0):

So I see your Type is wrong from the comments. Also the Source is not correct.

```
function getImages($dir) {
    global $imagetypes;

    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();

    // add trailing slash if missing
    if (substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir. = "/";

    // full server path to directory
    $fulldir = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/$dir";

    $d = @dir($fulldir) or die("getVideo: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    while (false !== ($entry = $d - > read())) {
        // skip hidden files
        if ($entry[0] == ".") continue;

        // check for image files
        $f = escapeshellarg("$fulldir$entry");
        $mimetype = trim(`file - bi $f`);
        foreach($imagetypes as $valid_type) {
            if (preg_match("@^{$valid_type}@", $mimetype)) {
                $retval[] = array(
                    'file' = > "$dir$entry",
                    'size' = > getimagesize("$fulldir$entry"));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    $d - > close();

    return $retval;
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
< div class = "vidSelect" >

<? php
// fetch image details
$video = getImages("video");

// display on page
foreach($video as $vid) {
    echo "<div class='vidContainer' src='{$vid['file']}' type='{$vid['size']['mime']}'></div>\n";
} ?>
< /div>
```